# openssl: exporting PFX to PEM and back

Tags: bash, openssl, pem, pfx, pkcs#12

I'm having trouble getting a working `.pfx` file from an exported `.pem`. I have read the various questions regarding the conversion, but they all deal with it in either direction and never both.

The german tax website "Elster" uses `.pfx` certificate files to sign in. On a form on the website, you provide the file and the associated password. I would like to be able to backup the certificate as plain text, rather than a binary file, so I thought of `pkcs12`. I tried exporting to a `.pem` file, which seems to work alright, but when I use the exported file to test my backup and write a `.pfx` back from it, the website doesn't accept my login ("invalid password for certificate file").

I have written a simple bash script that illustrates what I have in mind.
(It seems I have to use the `-legacy` parameter, otherwise my openSSL (3.1.1) will complain about unsupported formats.)

```bash
#!/bin/bash

pfxfile="./original.pfx"
pemfile="./export.pem"
pass="abc123"

# convert to PEM
openssl pkcs12 -in "$pfxfile" -legacy -passin pass:"$pass" -nodes -out "$pemfile"

# convert back to PFX
openssl pkcs12 -in "$pemfile" -legacy -export -passout pass:"$pass" -out "./restored.pfx"
```

I have tried exporting to seperate files for key, client cert and CA certs, which would be my preferred setup, but it didn't work either.
I know it's kind of hard to reproduce without the actual `.pfx` file, but I can't provide it for obvious reasons. I'm hoping somebody will see a simple error and that there is an easy fix. I was suspecting it has to do with the legacy format, but was not able to investigate it further.

Any help is appreciated!

Edit:

When I display info on the original and new `.pfx` files, the result differs quite a bit. Is there a way to generate the new file to more closely match the original?

**original.pfx**

```
MAC: sha1, Iteration 6000
MAC length: 20, salt length: 20
PKCS7 Data
Shrouded Keybag: pbeWithSHA1And3-KeyTripleDES-CBC, Iteration 6000
Shrouded Keybag: pbeWithSHA1And3-KeyTripleDES-CBC, Iteration 6000
PKCS7 Encrypted data: pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC, Iteration 6000
Certificate bag
Certificate bag
Certificate bag
Certificate bag
Certificate bag
Certificate bag
```

**restored.pfx**

```
MAC: sha256, Iteration 2048
MAC length: 32, salt length: 8
PKCS7 Encrypted data: PBES2, PBKDF2, AES-256-CBC, Iteration 2048, PRF hmacWithSHA256
Certificate bag
Certificate bag
Certificate bag
Certificate bag
Certificate bag
Certificate bag
PKCS7 Data
Shrouded Keybag: PBES2, PBKDF2, AES-256-CBC, Iteration 2048, PRF hmacWithSHA256
```